# Remove first character after a specific sequence

Tags: regex, r, string

I'm struggling to understand how to remove the first character after a specific sequence. To give an example:

```
string <- "26 765 64 673 762"
```

I would like to remove the first character after 76 and after 67, so the expected result would be:

```
string <- "26 76 64 67 76"
```

Any hint about how to do this using regex?

Comment: It is really easy with `gsub`, have you tried anything yet? Also, what about `4567`? Should it be `456`? Or if the input has `1671`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know a lot about regex so I can't really figure out how to do it. `4567` should stay as it is, `1671` should be `167`

Comment: Well, I still think it is very easy with a capturing group and a backreference: `gsub("(76|67).", "\\1", string)`. The `.` matches any char. `\\d` would match any digit.

Comment: Yes, it is easy if you know about regex, but I don't. Thank you, it works perfectly anyway. Any good place to start learning regex?

Comment: Backreferences might not be that basic, I agree. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html, also http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php, and you will get a grasp of how to use regexen with `gsub` in R. If you are going to use regular expressions in your code, you can benefit from reading at least that small bit on regex.

Comment: Just one last thing that I don't understand. If, instead of removing, I would need to replace with a space, would this `gsub("(76|67).", " ", string)` be the right syntax?

Comment: No, you need the `\1` *backreference* to insert back the `67` or `76` substring *captured* with the help of a *capturing group* `(67|76)`. So, you'd need `gsub("(67|76).", "\\1 ", string)` where `\\1` is `76` or `67` and a space is what you add to the string instead of any char *matched* with a `.`.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Sorry to come back so late, I am looking through the material you provided, but I am not able to figure out the syntax to match the next two character after a sequence instead of just the next one. What would be in that case?

Comment: Do you mean `gsub("(67|76)..", "\\1 ", string)`? Note the 2 dots. If there may be 1 or 2, just use  a `?` after the second dot: `gsub("(67|76)..?", "\\1 ", string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a mere

```
gsub("(76|67).", "\\1", string)
```

where `(76|67)` matches either `76` or `67` and `.` matches any character (since the `gsub` is used wihtout `perl=TRUE` argument, a TRE regex engine is used).

To only match a *digit* after `76` or `67`, use `\\d` or `[0-9]`:

```
gsub("(76|67)\\d", "\\1", string)
             ^^^
```

You need the `\1` *backreference* to insert back the `67` or `76` substring *captured* with the help of a *capturing group* `(67|76)`. So, you'd need `gsub("(67|76).", "\\1 ", string)` where `\\1` is `76` or `67` and a space is what you add to the string instead of any char *matched* with a `.`.

More on using regex for string replacement can be found at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) and some examples can be found [here](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern: `(?<=76|67)\d` with the global flag to match any single digit character after the strings `76` or `67. Then replace with nothing. You should have a replace method available to you.

You can always use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex. I've saved this expression for you to play with [here](https://regex101.com/r/fE6zU5/1).

The `(?<=76|67)` part is a positive look-behind. It looks for the pattern inside it, but does not include those characters in the resulting match. `76|67` means either the pattern `76` or the pattern `67`, so the lookbehind will match either one. Then the `\d` will match a single digit only after the lookbehind has been satisfied.

Or, as explained by Regex101 for `/(?<=76|67)\d/g`:

```
(?<=76|67) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
    1st Alternative: 76
        76 matches the characters 76 literally
    2nd Alternative: 67
        67 matches the characters 67 literally
\d match a digit [0-9]
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: After tried this `gsub(pattern = "(?<=76|67)\d","",temp)` I have this error 
`Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<=76|67)\d"`

Comment: My apologies, @adiana, I didn't notice you doing this in r. You have to escape the slashes in the regex with another slash. So use `\\d` instead.

Comment: This error now, replacing `\d` with `\\d` -> `  Error in gsub(pattern = "(?<=76|67)\\d", "", temp) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<=76|67)\d', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: Two comments: using a lookaround is not a problem, but sounds like an unnecessary since you can use a capturing group and a backreference (that might be easy to understand for regex beginners), and if you need to use a PCRE regex in R `gsub`, you should add `perl=TRUE` as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use \\w in gsub function to match the word after 76|67

```
gsub("(76|67)\\w","\\1",string)
```

[1] "26 76 64 67 76"